# where this path in in java nio

Tags: java, nio

i am learning `java.nio` so one of the tutorial give me that example

```
public class ReadFile {

public void getFileInformation() throws IOException {   
    /*try {
        //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        //System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    String file;
    file = "InputFile.txt";
    Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
    Path path = Paths.get(file);
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, charset);
}
}
```

he did not write any path he just assign it to String type with name of the file the path i know is like this `c://file//file//file` why is that and how to assign it to right path tutorial slide for this example [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/martyhall/java-7-tutorial-basic-file-io-with-the-nio-package)

Comment: In this Tut, the "InputFile.txt" is placed in the Project Directory, and with the Paths Helper class you can build a Path Object by Paths.get(file) and you dont need to know under which operating system your App runs. So place a File "InputFile.txt" under your Project Root and try this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relative file path such as `InputFile.txt` is a path to a file named `InputFile.txt`, and located in the current directory. The current directory is the directory from which the `java` command is executed.

Comment: is he saving the file information in List<String>

Comment: Yes; it reads all the lines, and stores them in a list, as the documentation of Files.readAllLines() explains: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29. You MUST learn to read documentation and not just guess what some code does or ask strangers.